# Как красиво записать мэппинг значения по диапазонам?

Tags: php

Есть входное значение, неск. десятков диапазонов в один из которых оно может попасть, и выходное значение для каждого.

Как лучше записывать такие конструкции в PHP — есть ли что-то лучше 50 строк типа `elseif( $in > NNN) $out = MMM;`?

Правила не формализуются до просто ф-ии с округлениями. Например:

```
function mapValue( $i){
    if( $i > 100)  return 67;
    elseif( $i>95) return 22;
    elseif( $i>35) return 13;
    elseif( $i>25) return 7;
    elseif( $i>10) return 3;
    else return 1;
}
```

Comment: эти диапазоны как определяются?

Comment: ну если использовать switch, но выгоду не так много. Присоединюсь к Марсу, есть какие-то причины чисел, чтобы подвести логику

Comment: Диапазоны стыкуются вплотную, обозначены граничными значениями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, поможет ли это вам, или нет, но когда мне пришлось проверять, входит ли число в диапазон значений, Я сделал так:

- Объявил массив диапазонов:

  $ranges = array(1,5,6,10,11,15);
- В приведенном выше примере 3 диапазона: 1-5, 6-10, 11-15
- В цикле проверяю, если $ranges[i] < ЧИСЛО < $ranges[i+1], значит ЧИСЛО входит в диапазон  с индексом i. К примеру, если ЧИСЛО=7, то приведенное выше условие сработает, когда i == 1.
- Пользуясь полученными данными можем смело заводить второй массив с соотношениями значений.

$relations = array(0 => 2, 1 => 8, 2 => 14);

- Просто получаем теперь нужное значение соотношения: $relations[i];

Простите за сумбур, 30 часов не спал уже :(

Comment: > 30 часов не спал уже :(

Немедленно выходите из ХэшКода! Сны - великая вещь. : )

Я вот тоже думал в сторону массивов. Логичнее всего было бы определить условия в ассоциативном массиве например, парами "нижняя граница"=>"выходное значение". И потом вставить пару с входным значением, и выудить ближайшие соседние ключ-значение.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге написал с массивами:

```
/**
 * Правила:
 * 0..10 ->     A
 * 11..30 ->    B
 * 31..100 ->   C
 * 101..200 ->  D
 */
function map( $in) {
    $ranges = array(0,11,31,101); // нижние границы диапазонов
    $values = str_split('ABCD'); // соответствующие им выходные значения
    $fix = in_array($in, $ranges) ? 0 : -1; 
    array_push($ranges, $in);
    sort( $ranges);
    $i = array_search( $in, $ranges);
    return $values[ $i + $fix];
}

$tests = array(1,11,31,96,500);
foreach( $tests AS $test) test($test);
function test( $i){ printf("%d\t%s\n", $i, map($i)); }
```

Тесты на выходе дают:

```
1       A
11      B
31      C
96      C
500     D
```

Краевые условия доводить напильником, если требуется. В любом случае, лучше пара массивов, чем сотня строк `elseif()`.